# Use of dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 3 `li` elements under the `#myc` element.

```
<div id="myc">
  <li>
    <div>http://www.example.com/?id=1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>http://www.example.com/?id=2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>http://www.example.com/?id=3</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

First, I want to hide the text with the URL inside the `div`. So I use this:

```
ff = jQuery("#myc li:nth-of-type(1) div:nth-child(7)"); // the url
ff.hide();
```

I use `div:nth-child(7)` because there are also other div elements inside the `li` which I didn't include here purely for clarity.

After hiding the `div` element, I want to make the whole `li` to be clickable and its link would be its relative url inside the `div` element. I use this:

```
cc = jQuery("#myc li:nth-of-type(1)"); // the li
cc.css("cursor", "pointer");
cc.click(function(){
    window.location.href = ff.text();
    return false;
});
```

Watch that I use `ff.text();` which means the URL of the `li` will be the content of its `div` child.

This works perfectly, but I happen to have a total of 3 elements as you saw in the markup. So I created 2 other copies of the above script and changed their relative numbers as such:

```
ff1 = jQuery("#myc li:nth-of-type(1) div:nth-child(7)"); // the url
ff1.hide();

ff2 = jQuery("#myc li:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-child(7)"); // the url
ff2.hide();

ff3 = jQuery("#myc li:nth-of-type(3) div:nth-child(7)"); // the url
ff3.hide();
```

I also did the same thing to the other script (making `li` clickable). I will not show that script here for post-size reasons.

As you understand this is working fine for 3 `li`s. But what if the outcome is 50 `li`s?

Is there any way I can use a `for` or some kind of a loop that will dynamically change the `li:nth-of-type(1)` to `li:nth-of-type(x)` and by x meaning a dynamic variable like x++; ?

Comment: 1) use an `a` if you want to navigate to a different document, it has all sorts of accessibility features your `li` doesn't have. 2) Can you add a special class or attribute on the `div` elements in question?

Comment: No unfortunately all this is generated by a shortcode which I cannot use " ". So i cant use A (because i have to use href="") and i cannot use class on the div because of class="".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than pulling out each `ff` element, use DOM traversal within the `click()` handler to find the related `div` to the clicked `li`, which contains the URL you want. This will allow you to have a single event handler applied to all `li`/`div` instances. Try this:

```
$("#myc li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).find('div:nth-child(7)').text();
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

Also note that `cc.css("cursor", "pointer");` and the hiding of the `div` elements should really be set in your CSS:

```
#myc li { cursor: pointer; }
#myc li div:nth-child(7) { display: none; }
```

Here's a working example of it all together:

```js
$("#myc li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).find('div:nth-child(7)').text();
  //window.location.href = url;
  console.log('redirecting to: ' + url);
});
```

```css
#myc li { cursor: pointer; }
#myc li div:nth-child(7) { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myc">
  <li>
    <span>Padding</span> <span>out</span> <span>some</span> <span>words</span> <span>for</span> <span>the index...</span>
    <div>http://www.example.com/?id=1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Padding</span> <span>out</span> <span>some</span> <span>words</span> <span>for</span> <span>the index...</span>
    <div>http://www.example.com/?id=2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Padding</span> <span>out</span> <span>some</span> <span>words</span> <span>for</span> <span>the index...</span>
    <div>http://www.example.com/?id=3</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: This was really fast! Thank you it worked perfectly! .find is really useful. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just dont understand what does e.preventDefault(); do?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. `preventDefault()` is a cleaner implementation of `return false` which still allows for event propagation

Answer (score 1):

try this::

```
var length = jQuery("#myc li").length;
for (i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    var selector = "#myc li:nth-of-type("+i+") div:nth-child(7)";
    jQuery(selector).hide();
    var cc = "#myc li:nth-of-type("+i+")"; 
    jQuery(cc).css("cursor", "pointer");
    jQuery(cc).click(function(){
    window.location.href = jQuery(selector).text();
      return false;
    });
}
```